# Populate list based on selection from separate list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There are a few topics that I have found while searching for an answer to this, but nothing that specifically helps my situation. Here's what I need to do and some background.

- Web application has a field called "Requested by" that automatically inputs the logged in users name from Active Directory. This cannot be edited.
- User selects a store location from the first list, this location is where the requested user will be setup for.
- Second list needs to then populate with a list of potential approvers by first seeing which store was selected, then grabbing a list of names from an Active Directory group called "Store Managers"

**Example**

Bob Jones is requesting a new logon for Sally Smith who will work at Store 1.

Bob selects "Store 1" from the first dropdown list

List 2 populates a list of approvers who are in "Store 1" group AND "Store Managers" group.

Can someone please tell me where to start on this! Any help is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the function that is called whenever the first drop-down menu changed, ie. a new value has been selected (such as selecting a store), you can have a simple if-else structure that, depending on the newly selected drop-down menu item, checks for any valid values within your Active Directory.

That is as specific as I can be, seeing as you haven't posted any code along with your question.